# Python | Почему элемент из списка не равен строке?

Tags: requests, discord, discord.py

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что питон не хочет признавать, что элемент из списка равен строке.
Вот код:

```
        if message.content.startswith('регистрация '):
            user = message.content.replace('регистрация ', '')
            r = requests.get("https://api.scratch.mit.edu/users/" + user, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
            r = r.json()
            r = r['profile']
            r = r['bio']
            r = r.split('\n')
            print('/.SCB' + str(message.author.id) + './')
            print(r[0])
            if r[0] == '/.SCB' + str(message.author.id) + './':
                users.append(message.author.mention)
                userscratch.append(user)
                safedata("users;/userscratch", f"{users};/{userscratch}")
                author = message.author
                guild = self.get_guild(тут айди)
                role = guild.get_role(тут айди)
                await author.add_roles(role)
                role = guild.get_role(тут айди)
                await author.remove_roles(role)
                await message.delete()
            else:
                print('-')
```

Вывод:

```
/.SCB770556756014530581./
/.SCB770556756014530581./
-
```

P.S. Использовал requests и discord.py

Comment: Пробовали поместить `'/.SCB' + str(message.author.id) + './'` в круглые скобки?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: А есть возможность воспроизвести ваш код? Тут возможно проблема в том, что у вас разные типы переменных. У вас массив r - это строковый массив?

Comment: @NkL322 Я провеял массивы и длину. Всё одинаково.

Comment: И всё же я бы попробовал напечатать тип переменной и посимвольно код каждого символа. Для обоих сравниваемых штук. Вплоть до того, что может там через backspace какой-то символ перебивается при печати. Или это какой-то хитрый тип данных, который при печати выглядит как строка, а при сравнении не ведёт себя как строка.